# 'Do' loop acting on a global variable

Tags: matrix, core-language, variable-definitions, clear

I need a code that will allow me to alter a `matrix` (a global variable) iteratively using a function `update` (which depends on variable `var`), append the value of a function `func` of the altered `matrix` to a list `mypoints`, and then reset the `matrix` to its original value. (In my code, I've already defined a matrix `matrix1` by `matrix=matrix` to make it easier to set the value of `matrix` at the end of the process.) The function `update` was given to me and is defined to alter this particular `matrix`- I can't change it to return a matrix output given a general matrix input, although I believe this would be a better option if I could.
I have the following code that I wish to define as a single function:

```
Do[update[var], 1000]
AppendTo[mypoints, {var, func[matrix]}]
Clear[matrix]
matrix = matrix1
```

This works for me, but I'd like to rewrite this code as a function of `var` so I can obtain many points. My naive/unsuccessful attempt is below, I'm not very familiar with the 'Do' loop so I don't know where to go from here, or if this can even be done. Any help is appreciated.

```
getpoints[var_] := Do[update[var]], 1000;
  AppendTo[mypoints, {var, func[matrix]}],
  Clear[matrix],
  matrix = matrix1]
```

Comment: Experiment with `f[x_]:=(y=2*x;z=x+1);y=5;z=1;f[12]` and see what the values of `y` and `z` are after that code runs. Maybe with that you can understand how to use that idea to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Check, for example, the documentation of [HoldFirst](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) (Applications section). If you want to define functions that modify other symbols, you need to hold the evaluation of those symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your first piece of code is working as intended, I think all you want to do is wrap it up as a function.

```
getpoints[var_] := (
  Do[update[var], 1000];
  AppendTo[mypoints, {var, func[matrix]}];
  Clear[matrix];
  matrix = matrix1)
```

A slightly cleaner method would be to use the dynamic scoping construct `Block`, which will allow you to modify `matrix` while the body of the block is evaluating, but will restore the original value afterwards (ie the same thing that you are doing manually with `matrix1`).

```
getpoints[var_] := Block[{matrix = matrix},
  Do[update[var], 1000];
  AppendTo[mypoints, {var, func[matrix]}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I explain the procedure with the help of an example: Consider the interactive calculation of a matrix invers, using several approximations. A necessary condition for this that the inverse of the diagonal is a first approximation, namely:

```
Norm[Identity- mat. DiagonalMatrix[1/Diagonal[mat]] < 1
```

We first search such a matrix:

```
n = 3;
id = IdentityMatrix[n];
While[mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]; 
 Norm[id - mat.DiagonalMatrix[1/Diagonal[mat]]] >= 1]
```

Then we define the update function. `var` chooses which approximation we want to use. And we define a function `fun` that gives a value for the error. We only iterate 4 times because the procedures converge pretty fast.

```
update[var_] := Switch[var
   , 1, #.(2 id - mat.#) & 
   , 2, #.(3 id - 3 mat.# + mat.#.mat.#) &
   , 3, #.(3 id - mat.#.(3 id - mat.#)) &
   , 4, (id + 1/4 (id - #.mat).(3 id - #.mat).(3 id - #.mat)).# &
   ];
fun[mat_, ivmat_] := Norm[Inverse[mat] - ivmat];
```

Finally we define `getpoints`, that first iterates the `update` and then appends the error to `mypoints`.

```
mypoints = {};
getpoints[mat_, var_] := 
  AppendTo[mypoints, 
   fun[mat, 
    Nest[update[var][#] &, DiagonalMatrix[1/Diagonal[mat]], 4]] ];
```

Now we calculate `getpoints` with different for `val` and look at the resulting errors:

```
getpoints[mat, 1];
getpoints[mat, 2];
getpoints[mat, 3];
getpoints[mat, 4];
 
mypoints
```